# Using Angular's 'ng-repeat' within a Responsive CSS Framework

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, frameworks, row, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS, so apologies if this is quite basic...

I want to use angular's 'ng-repeat' directive to repeat a section of html which gathers each individual object's data from the '$scope.projects' array in the controller.

I can do this fine. The problem I have is the original static document used the following html structure:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- start row 1 -->

  <div class="one-half column">
    *project 1 html here*
  </div>

  <div class="one-half column">
    *project 2 html here*
  </div>

</div> <!-- end row 1 -->

<div class="row"> <!-- start row 2 -->

  <div class="one-half column">
    *project 3 html here*
  </div>

  <div class="one-half column">
    *project 4 html here*
  </div>

</div> <!-- end row 2 -->
```

...and so on.

The repetitious code is contained within `<div class="one-half column"></div>` each time, so I have copied this into an html template referenced in directive file. This works fine.

My problem is the `<div class="row">` tags only occur every *other* time, and I don't know how to incorporate these into my code dynamically, enabling a theoretically endless controller array to spit out the correct html, with no need for manual adjustments to the view's html.

I considered placing the above custom directive within another custom directive with containing the `<div class="row">` tags, but I don't think ng-repeat will be able to handle this...?

Any ideas/solutions would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change step size for ngRepeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090522/change-step-size-for-ngrepeat)

Answer (score 0):

I would use ngIf with a modulus calculation.
On the lines of end row 1 and start row 2, use ng-if="$index % 2 === 0" or something like that.

This will only insert the tags if index is dividable with 2.

I haven't tested the code or syntax, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found another workaround - just structured the html/css so it bypassed the row/column structure. But thanks anyway, that's given me some ideas :)