# Join 3 columns to 3 other columns using bootstrap (regardless of size)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Boostrap and I have 2 rows that have 3 columns each.

As seen in the following image:

[image: 3 columns for each rows]

The problem in the bottom row is that the 3 columns are grouped in the same line, and what I want is for the 3 columns below to be almost glued to the 3 columns above (regardless of the size of the columns below ), Newspaper type.

As seen in the following image:

[image: expected result]

My code (simple HTML and Angular ng-repeat):

```
<div class="row">
   <div ng-repeat="channel in channels">
       <div ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>
       <div class="col-md-4 well">
           <h1 class="h1-class" style="margin-left: 20px">
            {{ channel.name }}
           </h1>
       </div>
   </div>
```

How can I achieve this friends?

Sorry if my question is wrong, I really did not know how to ask this. Greetings from Chile.

Comment: Why won't you try a single row and divide that row in 3 parts and put your boxes inside them with defined height and css to it

Comment: The problem is that there are many columns (8 rows of 3 columns) in the question I put 2 only as an example. And I want to do the same in all rows and for the moment I do not know how (using bootstrap). Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div style="height:30px;border:1px solid black;">Name 1</div>
        <div style="height:60px;border:1px solid black;">Name 4</div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div style="height:40px;border:1px solid black;">Name 2</div>
        <div style="height:30px;border:1px solid black;">Name 5</div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div style="height:20px;border:1px solid black;">Name 3</div>
        <div style="height:70px;border:1px solid black;">Name 6</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and it's how I want it, but how could I adapt it to ng-repeat? Greetings and thanks.

Comment: you can start by constructing each col-md-4 div first.  make three loops a loop for each div representing each column. the first loop should loop with index += 3 and the second loop will start from the secon element with index += 3 also and the third loop will start from the third element with index += 3

Comment: Thanks for your help friend, but inside each column I have to repeat 2 times an element and I can not find the logic to do it, could you help me? Thank you

Comment: you can use the view-model for reason from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090522/change-step-size-for-ngrepeat.                                                                         you can construct $scope.channels= [ [ {col1},{col4},{col7}],[{},{},{}] ]